# Distinct count values from multiple columns in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, distinct-values

Hello is there any function to count the distinct values of 3 or 4 columns so i do not have temp tables and other things. Also excel vba is not a case.

Like i want to count distinct languages in the table (it did not let me to place it as data). Do you want more info for help?
Also some cells could be empty.

[image]

Comment: Yes there is.  What specifically, depends on your data.  If you would mock up some test data and expected output, we can help more.  Otherwise the answer to your question is, "Yes".

Comment: COUNTIF() will do this, but I might use data validation to select which language is to be counted, needs a list of unique languages though.

Comment: it should be function t be written in cell. no work with menus so i can just place it in a cell and count

Comment: I have deleted my answer, as what the OP is showing currently is not their actual data setup.  There may be more than one language per cell separated by a `,`

Comment: no sorry i will make a different question place your answer please the only part that i want to be included here is what if a cell in the table is empty, but always only one value in cell exists no commas nothilg like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple reciprocal of a COUNTIF in a SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:C10<>"")/(COUNTIF(A2:C10,A2:C10)+(A2:C10="")))
```

[image]

Comment: perfect. may i make it more difficult. what if the data where already concatenated with , in one column so you had one column and lets say the first row of data was : Armenian,English,French

Comment: The languages in one row could be 2 and in another could be 5

Comment: you will need to separate them.  That is a different question than the one posed here.

Comment: yes i know this is a different question, do you think i should make also this one?

Comment: also the function has problem if a cell is empty

Comment: no do not change the question after you get an answer, as it opens the answer to down votes as it is no longer viable.  You will need to ask a new question.

Comment: Again you did not specify that.  You need to show what you have not what you think you can manipulate.

Answer (score 0):

Taking help of Scott i fount that

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A6:C14<>"")/(COUNTIF(A6:C14;A6:C14&"")))
```

will do the work